# LARAVEL 5.5 - Insert Data into Database from FORM with Eloquent Model

Tags: database, laravel-5, model, eloquent, database-connection

I have a problem with inserting Data into Database.

All i have done till now is :

Create a Model with Controller and Migration via:

```
php artisan make:model Cars -mcr
```

So, now all of my files looks this way :

### Cars - Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cars extends Model
{

}
```

### AddCar.blade.php - View

```
<form action="{{ action('CarsController@store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="brand" placeholder="Marka">
    <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model">
    <input type="text" name="doors" placeholder="Ilość drzwi">
    <input type="text" name="priceHour" placeholder="Cena za godzinę">
    <input type="text" name="priceDay" placeholder="Cena za dzień">
    <input type="text" name="priceWeek" placeholder="Cena za tydzień">
    <input type="text" name="priceMonth" placeholder="Cena za miesiąc">
    <input type="text" name="priceYear" placeholder="Cena za rok">
    <input type="submit" value="Osadź">

</form>
```

### CarsController - Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cars;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CarsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return "test";
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $cars = new Cars;
        $cars->brand = $request->input('brand');
        $cars->brand = $request->input('model');
        $cars->brand = $request->input('type');
        $cars->brand = $request->input('doors');
        $cars->priceHour = $request->input('priceHour');
        $cars->priceDay = $request->input('priceDay');
        $cars->priceWeek = $request->input('priceWeek');
        $cars->priceMonth = $request->input('priceMonth');
        $cars->priceYear = $request->input('priceYear');
        $cars->save();
        return redirect('admin.AddCar');
    }
```

### web.php - Routing

```
Route::resource('/cars', 'CarsController');
```

### Migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCarsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->string('model');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('doors');
            $table->string ('priceHour')->nullable();
            $table->string('priceDay')->nullable();
            $table->string('priceWeek')->nullable();
            $table->string('priceMonth')->nullable();
            $table->string('priceYear')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cars');
    }
}
```

Error I receiving after fill out all fields and click "Osadz" = submit is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'model' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `cars` (`brand`, `priceHour`,
>   `priceDay`, `priceWeek`, `priceMonth`, `priceYear`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (3, 3, 53, 3, 35, 3, 2018-01-30 09:36:57,
>   2018-01-30 09:36:57))

And my question is, what default value is missing in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"model"

You should add the field 'model' in your Cars's Model, fillable fields.

Or if you don't want to give it a value at first, in the migrating file, you can add ->nullable() to the field.

Comment: yes, if you have it, the problem is the field. Look at your query that is being send to the DB - " insert into cars (brand, priceHour,  priceDay, priceWeek, priceMonth, priceYear, updated_at, created_at". You don't try to add 'model' field at all. This is the problem

Comment: $cars->brand = $request->input('brand');
        $cars->brand = $request->input('model');
        $cars->brand = $request->input('type');
        $cars->brand = $request->input('doors');

Comment: You used $cars->brand 4 times, change $cars->brand, to $cars->model

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, you are brilliant !

Already solved the problem, i missed out the field in the View :

```
<input type="text" name "type" placeholder="Typ"/>
```

which can not be NULL

and i "fix" the model with :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cars extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        "brand", "model" , "type" , "doors" , "priceHour" ,
        "priceDay" , "priceWeek" , "priceMonth" , "priceYear"
        ];
}
```

Thank you and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the model column in your table as either nullable or give it a default value in the migration file. The error is stating this input is missing:

```
<input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model">

// examples for your migration
$table->string('model')->nullable();
// or
$table->string('model')->default('foo');
```

Alternatively if neither of those works for, then add validation to ensure the correct data gets submitted to your controller.

In your controller you can define the rules like so:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'model' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'Brand' => 'required|string',
    ......
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

here QuartUpdatManufacturs is the model name, in which directly insert the values.$request have some values.

```
$insert_id = Module::insert("QuartUpdatManufacturs", $request);
```